# How can i hide in game view a ui button and show the button when pressing the escape key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the editor i did in the menu: GameObject > UI > Button
Now i have in the Hierarchy a Canvas with a a Button.
Now i want when i'm running the game that it will not show the button, and only when i press the escape key it will show the button.

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class NodesGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

     public Button btnGenerate;

     private void Start()
     {
         Button btn = btnGenerate.GetComponent<Button>();
         btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
     }

     void TaskOnClick()
     {
         Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
     }
```

I want that when i press the escape key the btn will show and escape again will not show. The default state when running the game is not showing the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagining that by "hiding" you mean that you deactivate the object holding your button, you need to check in an Update function if you hit the Escape key or not. If you did hit it, you just need to reverse the active state of your button, and you're done.

As a side note, in your Start function, you do not need to get your Button component again, as you already have it referenced in your btnGenerate variable. So you can directly add the listener to your btnGenerate variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NodesGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button btnGenerate;

     private void Start()
     {
         btnGenerate.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
     }

     void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
         {
             btnGenerate.gameObject.SetActive(!btnGenerate.gameObject.activeSelf);
         }
     }

     void TaskOnClick()
     {
         Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
     }
}
```